# Excel Pivot Chart with Dynamic Date Calculations

Tags: excel

## Upfront Apology

This is my bumbling attempt to verbalize the problem I am trying to solve, so please accept my apology if I have failed. My only hope is that someone understands it and has already found a solution that works.

## Background

I have been tasked to analyze and report on data from our service desk ticketing system. The data from this system includes the following fields:

| Field Name | Date type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ticket Number | Numeric | Unique serialized ID |
| Ticket type | Text | Category of action requested |
| Requestor | Text | Name of customer |
| Date created | Date | Date the ticket was submitted by the customer |
| Date closed | Date | Date the ticket was completed (null if open) |
| Ticket status | Text | Open, completed, cancelled, etc. |
| Assignee | Text | Specialist assigned to work the request |

## Toolset

I am using `Excel 365` to analyze and summarize this data, making use of the `Power Query`, `Data Model`, `KPIs` and `Pivot Table` features. My long-term goal is to possibly migrate this to a `Power BI` dashboard, but I have no experience in that at the moment.

## Time-Based Presentation

One of the things I need to do in this project is to produce a dashboard-type pivot chart that graphically shows the following for each point on the timeline:

- Number of tickets opened
- Number of tickets closed
- Number of currently active tickets (not closed or cancelled)
- Average age of open tickets (in business days)
- Met goal stated in service level agreement (true/false KPI)

### Dynamic data in timeline

The reporting of the operational status of each ticket will change based upon the date it was closed. For example, if a ticket was opened on 7/1 and closed on 7/5, it should:

- Not reflect in the timeline totals prior to 7/1
- Reflect in the timeline totals as `Active` on 7/1 through 7/4, and
- Reflect in the timeline totals as `Closed` on and after 7/5

### Are Dynamic Summaries Possible?

Is this kind of dynamic reporting possible in pivot charts? If not, how can this kind of reporting dashboard be constructed?

### Dynamic Age computation?

Is it possible to have the age of open tickets be dynamic in the timeline for the time period in which it was/is active? Using the example above, in the timeline at the 7/1 point, the age of this data point will be 1, and at 7/4 the age will be calculated as 4; then from 7/5 onward, the age of that data point would be set to 5.

## Training or Tutorials?

Do you know of any videos or courses that show how to create this kind of presentation?

Comment: Without using PowerQuery, PivotTables or PowerBi, I would look to use functions like countif(), countifs(), sumif(), sumifs(), averageif(), averageifs() etc (there are others that you might find useful) to get a "feel" for your data and  also provide checks to make sure that later reporting using PowerQuery etc gives expected results. Also check the data for errors as leading and trailing spaces are a classic source of issues.

Comment: I'm sorry f I was not clear, but I AM using PowerQuery, PivotTables, M, DAX, KPIs and Data Model for this; my challenge is trying to wrap my mind around if this is even possible. With my current level of knowledge, it does not look like it's possible to have dynamically computed totals, so I am hoping I am wrong about this.